# Controller cannot insert into notification table in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, notifications

So I have one primary table `comment` that has a number of fields. Then
I want to insert some fields into a `notifications` table whenever a new record is inserted into `comment` table.

In the controller, initially I had this and it worked for `comment` table:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Comment;
    if (isset($_POST['Comment'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Comment'];
        if ($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->comment_id));
    }
    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Then I put some more lines for the `notification` table. But it didn't work.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Comment;
    $notif = new Notifications;
    if (isset($_POST['Comment'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Comment'];
        $notif->peg = 'nofriani';
        $notif->tanggal = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
        $notif->notif = ' mengirimkan berita ';
        $notif->isi = $_POST['Comment']['post_id'];
        $notif->link = 'links';
        $notif->save();
        if ($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->comment_id));
    }
    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

The function for `comment` table still works. But the one for `notifications` table doesn't. I tried to rearrange the positions but nothing happened. I also changed the `$notif->save();` into `$notif->insert();` but still nothing happened. What have I missed?

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notifications (
   id_notif int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   tanggal date NOT NULL,
   peg varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   notif text NOT NULL,
   isi varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   link varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id_notif)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: Write your database table description

Comment: Okay, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find any mistakes in your code.

Bellow are my assumptions to debug above task

1. May be `$_POST['Comment']['post_id']` is not supplying the value.
2. Print Post values and check whether you are getting all necessary values.

   ```
    print_r($_POST['Comment']);
   ```
3. Validate `$notif` model before `save()`. It will display the validation errors if your model has.

   ```
   echo CActiveForm::validate($notif);
   ```

You can write above code in a better way as bellow.

```
    $model = new Comment;
    $notif = new Notifications;
    if (isset($_POST['Comment']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Comment'];
        if ($model->validate() && $model->save())
        {
            $notif->peg = 'nofriani';
            $notif->tanggal = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
            $notif->notif = ' mengirimkan berita ';
            $notif->isi = $_POST['Comment']['post_id']; 
            $notif->link = 'links';                
            if($notif->validate() && $notif->save())
            {
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->comment_id));                    
            }       
            else
            {
                echo CActiveForm::validate($notif); 
                Yii::app()->end();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model); 
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
```